# C++ Choose template output type for input type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, types, casting

Consider I want to implement the following function:

```
template<typename InputType, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<InputType>::value>::type>
inline InputType degreeToRadians(InputType degree)
{
    return degree * (PI / 180.0);
}
```

How do I find the correct OutputType for the given InputType? Since the InputType could be some integral number the function would return a wrong result because the calculated number is casted to the integral InputType. I have also considered to just return a long double (the largest floating point number I think) but it seems like a waste of memory. What would you suggest to solve this problem?
By the way I DON'T want to include template specifications whenever i call this function:

```
float someFloat = degreeToRadians<float>(someIntegral);
```

Comment: `inline auto degreeToRadians(InputType degree) -> decltype(degree * (PI / 180.0))` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, could that not be simplified to `decltype(degree * 1.0)`?

Comment: Just saw this question is tagged C++11. Go for Piotr's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++11:

```
template<typename InputType,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<InputType>::value>::type>
auto degreeToRadians(InputType degree)
-> decltype(degree * (PI / 180.0))
{
    return degree * (PI / 180.0);
}
```

In C++14:

```
template<typename InputType,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<InputType>::value>>
auto degreeToRadians(InputType degree)
{
    return degree * (PI / 180.0);
}
```

BTW, you probably want to do the computaion with `InputType`, I mean that `PI` and `180` have type `InputType` instead.